# AdMob banner ads not showing and not showing an explanation

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, admob

I created an app and connected it with admob. It was working fine for one week. Then.. it just stopped on Android ? I created sample app with my implementation of it 1:1 with my base app to see if it's related with something else than just admob ?  Below i put my code for admob which i used.

Controler in PCL:

```
public class AdMobView : View
{
    public enum Sizes { Standardbanner, LargeBanner, MediumRectangle, FullBanner, Leaderboard, SmartBannerPortrait }
    public Sizes Size { get; set; }
    public AdMobView()
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.Accent;
    }
}
```

Android adrenderer

```
public class AdMobRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
    Context context;

    public AdMobRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(e.OldElement == null)
        {
            var adView = new AdView(Context);
            switch ((Element as AdMobView).Size)
            {
                case AdMobView.Sizes.Standardbanner:
                    adView.AdSize = AdSize.Banner;
                    break;
                case AdMobView.Sizes.LargeBanner:
                    adView.AdSize = AdSize.LargeBanner;
                    break;
                case AdMobView.Sizes.MediumRectangle:
                    adView.AdSize = AdSize.MediumRectangle;
                    break;
                case AdMobView.Sizes.FullBanner:
                    adView.AdSize = AdSize.FullBanner;
                    break;
                case AdMobView.Sizes.Leaderboard:
                    adView.AdSize = AdSize.Leaderboard;
                    break;
                case AdMobView.Sizes.SmartBannerPortrait:
                    adView.AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner;
                    break;
                default:
                    adView.AdSize = AdSize.Banner;
                    break;
            }
            adView.AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
            var testDeviceId = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
            var requestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("c793762db79ab2c6");
            Console.WriteLine("Android device id is: {0}", testDeviceId);
            adView.LoadAd(requestBuilder.Build());
            SetNativeControl(adView);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity Andorid

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        var id = "my-app-id-with-~"; 
        MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, id);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

MainPage

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdMobFixed"
         xmlns:adMob="Ad"
         x:Class="AdMobFixed.MainPage">

<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <local:AdMobView 
                         MinimumWidthRequest="400"
                         MinimumHeightRequest="100"
                         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
    </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```

One week ago i didn't have to use min requests. Unfortunately i broke my phone with android OS so i can't test it out of my PC. Below i attached my output:

02-23 17:14:47.015 D/DynamitePackage(19883): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl

02-23 17:14:47.025 I/Ads     (19883): This request is sent from a test device.

02-23 17:14:47.096 I/DynamiteModule(19883): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:11140

02-23 17:14:47.097 I/DynamiteModule(19883): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 11140

Android Manifest is also updated with internet permission and network state. I also added activity tag between aplication tags.

I were using nuget Ads lite form google and i did test it on full play.ads from google.

For any help i would be very happy. Thank you in Advance ! :)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.You can post your issue on Google Developer Forum.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code:MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, id);
 on the line below the:
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: I just tried this, still same output and no success :(